# How to dynamically load a content in a template

Tags: php, html

I have 6 files.

1. header.php
2. footer.php
3. home.php
4. page1.php
5. page2.php
6. index.php

**header.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
<li><a href="home.php>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="page1.php>Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="page2.php>Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
```

**footer.php**

```
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

    include "header.php";
    //content goes here
    include "home.php";  //this include must change when i click on page 1 or page 2 link    
    //content goes here
    include "footer.php";

?>
```

How can i dynamically change the content of index.php when i click on the links?

Comment: Why don't you create pages and give links?

Comment: you want to replace `include "home.php";` with `include "page1.php";` is that what you want.? If so why dont you create links ?

Comment: Well i want only index.php to handle everything. I only want to create pages that will be loaded by index.php

Comment: Check Smarty http://www.smarty.net/ Template engine. Maybe it will help you. You can add variables into tmp files and modify it later, you can also call and include different files etc. Something similar you can do with your system but i recommend you to try Smarty. It build for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main structure :

```
index.php --> Layout + handles which page to display
header.php --> Included in index
footer.php --> Include in index
```

Links would be something like `index.php?page=home`

index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

    <?php 

       // Handle here what page to include : 
       // - Store $_GET['page']
       // - Sanitize the var
       // - Check if you have a file that would correspond to this page
       // - Include it

    ?>

    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

header.php :

```
<header>
    ....
</header>
```

footer.php :

```
<footer>
 .....
</footer>
```

Answer (score -2):

You will need a different script for each URL:

**index.php**

```
<?php

    include "header.php";
    //content goes here
    include "home.php";  
    //content goes here
    include "footer.php";

?>
```

**page1.php**

```
<?php

    include "header.php";
    //content goes here
    include "page1_content.php"; //contains contents of page1
    //content goes here
    include "footer.php";

?>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php

    include "header.php";
    //content goes here
    include "page2_content.php"; //contains contents of page2
    //content goes here
    include "footer.php";

?>
```

Comment: By doing this i'll be needing to create extra files?

Comment: This would be just the same as if OP would put header and footer.php inside page2_content.php (or home / page1_content).